# Browse file system in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to browse the file system in Azure Devops. Like when using SSH to connect to a server? Or if it's possible to browse using Explorer.

It would really simplify things if I could see what files were created and where they end up after builds.

Now I don't feel I have any way to know which files ended up where after the builds are done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t think so. You may add build steps ([Build and release tasks - Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#utility)) and create cmd or bath file to browse the file system of the build servers.

As alternative way, you may use your own build server ([Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install)) on Azure VMs and you will have the full control.

Comment: I suppose adding a custom build step is the best approach. Thanks!